# Clearing Buffer Memory in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I make a app which include a image view within scroll view.
I have 3 classes and each class add images into image view.

When i press button1, it call class1 and it fill Class1images(from image001 to image200).
When i press button2, it call class2 and it fill Class2images(from image201 to image400)

The problem is when i call class1, image view show class1images(from image001 to image200).
After calling class1, i call class2.
When i call class2, my image view can't show class2images(from image201 to image400)
But, class1Images (from image001 to image200) are remaining in app.

I think class1 images are still in memory, so that class2 images can't add to memory.
I want to remove class1images when i call class2.
When i call next class, it will remove old images in memory and replace with new images.

But, my app is develop with storyboard and ARC.
So, i can't release memory manually in ARC mode.
Is there any ways to remove old images in memory?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super loadView];  
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 200;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    // Create a UIImage to hold Info.png
    UIImage *image1  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image001.jpg"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image002.jpg"];
:
:
UIImage *image200 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image200.jpg"];

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2, . . . ,image200,nil];

    ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [ImageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    [ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];}
```

ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*numberOfViews,self.view.frame.size.height);

```
[self.view addSubview:ScrollView];}
```

Comment: show some code.. dont get how you hooked stuff up

Comment: this isn't about whats left in memory at all. please make the title more descriptive and about what you are tring to do

Comment: what is the role of your class ? and are you adding images dynamically to scrollview. And please post code as Daji-Djan said.

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience, i add images into array at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

setting an imageview's `animationImages` property to a new array will remove the olf array and animate the new one.

to be 110% safe call stopAnimation, set the images, call startAnimation

Answer (score 0):

I think your scrollview is not getting cleaned up. You need to remove previous images from scrollView and after that add images from next class.

try to implement something like this for removing images from scrollview and after this add other images on button click

```
for(UIView *subView in self.ScrollView.subviews)
{
    if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Hopefully can help you. Just give it a try.

Comment: thanks you for your help. I'm sorry for my late response.  I use different  view controller for different classes. I don't use only one view controller for different classes. So, each class has their vc and each vc has one scroll view. How can i clean for each scroll view?

Comment: if each class has separate xib then this should not be case. Any way give it a try and also post your code for calling class on button click.

Comment: i use storyboard and it include three view controller.  Each view controller has their class. VC1 has Class1.h and Class1.m VC2 has Class2.h and Class2.m. In m file, i create image view and add images into image view. Then i add this image to scroll view.  At this case, after i use around 200 images, another images can't add into image view. At first, i think this is memory problem. So, i reduce image size and try again (reduce from 300Mb to 30Mb). But, it did not work. I have no idea how should i do.